# Django SQLite regex query is slow. Local SQLite regex query is fast. Why?

Tags: django, sqlite

I have a small SQLite3 app that's basically a database search.

`models.py`

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key = True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index = True, blank = True, null = True)
```

When I do

```
from main.models import Customer
queryset = Customer.objects
names = queryset.filter(name__regex = "[^aeiou]ica$")
list(names)
```

in `./manage.py shell`, Django takes up to 5 seconds to return this result.

Meanwhile on my local machine, if I do the same query in the sqlite shell,

```
sqlite> select * from main_customer where name regexp "[^aeiou]ica$";
```

I get the result in less than a second.

Where does the difference come from? Can Django be made to match the speed of my local query?

Comment: Without model definitions, I don't know if there are extra operations slowing it down, for example, in its `__str__()` method, but you could try comparing your SQL with the result of `str(Customer.objects.queryset.filter(name__regex = "[^aeiou]ica$").query)` to start.

Comment: @EdoardoFacchinelli Ciao, I've added the models.py for you to take a look at, if you'd like.

Comment: I don't see anything weird in the model either tbh. My next step would be to check the SQL Django is running with the command above, or for short `str(names.query)`. Once you have that you can compare and try to prepend `EXPLAIN`. If they are also the same, it could be some operation being run on the string representation for the REPL (hence why I asked about `__str__`), I once had that with a debugger attached.